# Как реализовать такую задумку дизайнера?

Tags: javascript, css, css3, html5, вёрстка

Есть навигация по квизу (опроснику), который имеет несколько шагов. По задумке дизайнера, в зависимости от того, какое состояние шагов (заполненный, пропущенный, по дефолту) линия имеет разную окраску на отдельных участках.

Очевидно, что здесь нужно использовать градиент, но каким образом такое можно реализовать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я тут подумал... Затупил: Не обязательно ведь делать одну сплошную линию со сложным градиентом) Можно между каждой парой точек разместить отдельный блок с градиентом, тогда сильно проще будет организовать цвета: Каждый градиент всего из 2-х цветов)

Comment: Спасибо! Сейчас такой вариант как раз и делаю. Тоже подумал, что так будет намного проще, если сделать линию из нескольких элементов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Основная идея:

```css
div {
  height: 2px;
  background-image:
    repeating-linear-gradient(
      to right,
      transparent,
      transparent 2px,
      white 2px,
      white 3px),
      
    linear-gradient(to right,
      red 10%,
      #2ff 30%,
      red 50%,
      black 70%,
      #2ff 90%
    );
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Конечно придется хорошо так повозиться с процентами, цветами и их переключением из JS. И не факт, что такое решение будет легче, чем заполнение "в лоб" из JS, через массив цветов (или, хранить только основные цвета в RGB, а шаг - вычислять в цикле) в мелкие квадратики по 2px.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы добиться прерывистой линии можно попробовать использовать border. То есть между круглыми элементами создаётся блок высотой 0 и длиной равной расстоянию между этими круглыми элементами. Этому элементу задать свойство border-top или border-bottom. А цвет указать linear-gradient